# Browser Plugin Development

Tags: browser

I want to develop plugins and extensions for browsers like in the Chrome web store, but I do not know where to get started. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need knowledge of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Then, you can start [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).

> **Resources**
>
> [Getting Started (Hello World!
>   extension)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)
>   [Chrome Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html)
>   [Chrome APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which browser you want to extend. Then find tutorials, documentation, existing opensource extensions and code, code and code..

For chrome [here is extension tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html), start there..